# What "projective space" is this?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3$.  Then given, $x, y, z$, let $\{(ap^x, bp^y, cp^z): p \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be an equivalence class.  Has this space of points been studied in relation to solutions of multivariate polynomials?

Comment: You can try to google "weighted projective space". This is the set you have described. There are lots of articles about it.

Comment: Does this fall under algebraic geometry?

Comment: Yes. But I don't think "algebraic number theory" is an appropriate tag.

Comment: You should require $x,y,z$ to be integers.